# How to handle dependant validations on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I've some Active Record validations on my model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { is: 10 }
end
```

That seems fine. It validates that the field `name` is not `nil`, `""` and that it must have exactly 10 characters. Now, if I want to add a [custom validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators), I'd add the `validate` call:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { is: 10 }
  validate :name_must_start_with_abc

  private

  def name_must_start_with_abc
    unless name.start_with?('abc')
      self.errors['name'] << 'must start with "abc"'
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is: when the `name` field is `nil`, the `presence_of` validation will catch it, but won't stop it from validating using the custom method, `name_must_start_with_abc`, raising a `NoMethodError`, as `name` is `nil`.

To overcome that, I'd have to add a nil-check on the `name_must_start_with_abc` method.

```
def name_must_start_with_abc
  return if name.nil?

  unless name.start_with?('abc')
    self.errors['name'] << 'must start with "abc"'
  end
end
```

That's what I don't wan't to do, because if I add more "dependant" validations, I'd have to re-validate it on each custom validation method.

How to handle dependant validations on Rails? Is there a way to prevent a custom validation to be called if the other validations haven't passed?

Comment: Please elaborate why you do not want to do what you did in the bottom. What`s wrong with that?

Comment: I agree with @UmeshMalhotra you have a conditional so that must live somewhere.  You can either combine them into a single validation, keep like it is, or more it to an external service object but any of those methods will have a conditional.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can implement that specific validation in a single line of code - thus negating the problem of adding additional checks: `validates :name, presence: true, length: { is: 10 }, format: { with: /\Aabc/ }`

Comment: Also, my advice would be to not think of the above as "re-validating on the same condition". That's not what you're doing. You're adding a guard clause to the validation. `return if name.nil?` is a small, perfectly reasonable guard clause - and it does not duplicate the "present and length 10" check made earlier. If you find that the validations are far more convoluted than this, then perhaps there's a bigger issue with your application design - but I cannot really advise without more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no perfect solution unless you write all your validations as custom methods. Approach I use often:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { is: 10 }
  validate :name_custom_validator

  private

  def name_custom_validator
    return if errors.include?(:name)

    # validation code
  end
end
```

This way you can add as many validations to `:name` and if any of them fails your custom validator won't execute. But the problem with this code is that your custom validation method must be last.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { is: 10 }
  validate :name_must_start_with_abc, unless: Proc.new { name.nil? }

  private

  def name_must_start_with_abc
    unless name.start_with?('abc')
      self.errors['name'] << 'must start with "abc"'
    end
  end
end
```

Please check [allow_blank](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank), [:allow_nil](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil) and [conditional validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) as well for more options.

Comment: Try `p = Product.new` and `p.valid?`. It will trigger a `NoMethodError`.